# Using representation theory to prove subgroup

Tags: representation-theory

Good evening,

I don't manage to solve the following problem :  Is the cyclic group of order 5, Z5, a subgroup of the group Su(2)  ?  And for SU(3)  ?

Is it possible to solve this using representation of Z5 or have I to show it "by hand "  ? Because I don't really see a theorem that give a link between the representation of a subgroup abd these from the group himself.

Thank you very much and excuse my english because it is not my native language

Comment: @abnry How would that help for this specific question?

Comment: All you have to do is to check whether or not there is an element of order $5$.

Comment: It was just that i see a proof using representation theory but it seems very suspect to me

Answer (score 2):

Let $\zeta$ be a $n-$th root of unity. Then, the group generated by $$A = \begin{pmatrix} \zeta & 0 \\ 0 & \zeta^{-1} \end{pmatrix}$$

is cyclic of order $n$. Also notice that you can embedd $SU_2$ in $SU_3$ so it is also true for $SU_3$.

In fact, the finite subgroups of $SU_2$ corresponds to finite subgroups of $SL_2(\Bbb C)$ : up to conjugacy, the list is $C_n$, the dihedral groups $D_n$ (for all $n \geq 1$), $\mathfrak S_4$, $\mathfrak A_4$ and $\mathfrak A_5$. It corresponds to ADE diagrams and there are many interesting connexions with algebraic geometry, representation theory and Lie algebras.